# Input Mask for 00:00 am - 00:00 pm

Tags: jquery, input, mask, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm using the [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) plugin.

I need a mask for a time range in 12 hour format.

Example: 9:30 am - 10:00 pm

I know we can do something like this:

```
$(selector).inputmask("h:s t");
```

I was hoping to get something like this:

```
$(selector).inputmask("h:s t - h:s t"); // not working as intended
```

The closest I can get is this:

```
$(selector).inputmask("9{1,2}:99 aa - 9{1,2}:99 aa");
```

...but it's not ideal/perfect since this will pass: 33:44 mm - 55:66 nn

Comment: Why not use http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ instead? It gives you what you need and much more...

Comment: @Dekel It's a great plugin but I prefer input mask since I use it in combination with dataTables and x-editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after reading inputmask.date.extensions.js and added some adjustments:

```
$(selector).inputmask({
    mask: "h:s t\\m - h:s t\\m",
    placeholder: "hh:mm xm - hh:mm xm",
    alias: "datetime",
    hourFormat: "12"
});
```

This solution is not perfect since it gives me the leading zeros for the hours which I don't want, but at least it's better than this:

```
$(selector).inputmask("9{1,2}:99 aa - 9{1,2}:99 aa");
```